# Understanding the Magento 2 checkout_index_index.xml

Tags: magento2

With Magento 2 how can I view the full checkout_index_index to gain a better understanding of it.

I need to make some modifications to it but need to know the appropriate layout for nesting all of the tags...

Is there a way to clearly visualize this on the front end perhaps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can install the Knockout context debugger extension in Google Chrome browser.

Then inspect an element e.g. Phone Number's label.

For me it was on the right side I was able to view the Knockout context after clicking on the >>> button. Should the panel be wider this would not be required.

On the Knockout context there is a namespace property.

For example:  "checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.street"

Where every . is a children node in the XML and the words/identifiers in between are the <item name="...."> parts.


Maybe this is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can understand below link
1. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html

2. https://inviqa.com/blog/technical-guide-magento-2-checkout

Comment: It helps but not full XML that is used.

I was able to figure out the names of each part from inspecting in chrome with the Knockout context debugger extension by looking at the namespace value.

Thanks.